# How do I change my resolution to 1600*900 for a wide screen monitor?

Tags: 11.10, resolution

How do I change my  resolution to 1600*900 for a wide screen monitor in Oneiric? 
My Hardware configuration is as below:

```
madhu@madhu-Home:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AGP Port (virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge)
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 [IDE] (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.3 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
00:1f.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
madhu@madhu-Home:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You did not specify if you are using a Laptop with integrated screen or a desktop computer with external screen (and which manufactor, model number)? This would be helpful.

If the last is the case: Do you use a DVI cable? It might be possible that Ubuntu is not able to determine the right resolution using a VGA cable.

1. You are using a

   VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)

This cheap chip is not well supported under linux, your system uses now the standard VESA driver which is slow and only lasts a maximum of 1024x768 resolution. If you are using a desktop computer and really solve the problem without fiddling around, I would suggest to get the cheapest possible nvidia graphics card - either a new one or used one at exxx - and your problems should be completely solved (after installing the proprietary nvidia driver with jockey-gtk). Sorry to tell you about this. See e.g. [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861023%22Silicon%20Integrated%20Systems%20%5BSiS%5D%20771/671%20PCIE%20VGA%20Display%20Adapter%20%22)

Greets
Axel

Comment: Thanks Axel! That was the best piece of advise i could get;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

Click the top right icon, choose `Displays...`

[image: displays]

Change `Resolution`.

[image: resolution]

Done?

Comment: Nope! There is no display resolution 1600*900 in the display. Think the issue is a little more complex than that!!:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity, open the dash and search for "displays". It is a settings window that lets you choose the resolution of your monitor(s) and some other options.

Comment: Nope! There is no display resolution 1600*900 in the display. Think the issue is a little more complex than that!!:-)

Comment: I suppose that you have already checked, but I'll ask anyway: are you sure that your monitor and your graphics card support that resolution?